# Code Review missing from Stack Exchange footer

Tags: bug, design

Graduated sites are listed on the footer pages of all other Stack Exchange sites. Consider this list [from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/):

[image: SOFooter]

(similarly on [Meta.Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) )

I notice that other recently "designed" sites are up there (Biology, Chemistry)....

Comment: @NormalHuman - that's all a matter of opinion.... the Code Review graduation was announced 22 Sept 2014... 3 days after Chemistry, and 5 months before Biology.

Comment: @NormalHuman - Stack exchange has been quite clear recently that the site's graduation status, and their design, are not time-linked. A site is graduated when the graduation is announced.

Comment: Isn't this a better question for [the big meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 4):

Based on an assumption that the shown list is based on some precalculated metric, I compared Code Review to the last on the list, ExpressionEngine® Answers, and here are the stats:

- **Code Review** - *Q&A for peer programmer code reviews*
  29k questions, 50k answers, 94% answered, 76k users,
  47k visits/day, 34 questions/day, 4y11m site age
- **ExpressionEngine® Answers** - *ExpressionEngine® Answers Q&A for administrators, end users, developers and designers for ExpressionEngine® CMS*
  11k questions, 14k answers, 80% answered, 4.2k users,
  1.3k visits/day, 6.0 questions/day, 3y1m site age

Sadly I can't see why this site is shown, and Code Review isn't. As such this isn't an answer as to why Code Review doesn't show, but it is a confirmation that it doesn't seem to be metric based, and that it is possibly a somewhat static list, which could need a little refactoring.

Comment: I can't find my information at the moment but I'm sure I've read somewhere that the footer listed sites by ages of graduation.